# forkJoin or zip (or maybe some other function) list of observables with some kind of a progress

Tags: rxjs

Is there a way to gather a list of observables together to get cumulative result like `forkJoin` or `zip` does, but get some kind of a progress while they finishes?
For example join a list of similar http requests but visualize the progress while they goes.

Comment: This question needs a lot more details. What have you tried? Tell us more about how the observables are created, and what values they produce? Observables do not magically emit progress updates unless they are created to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you work out the percentage as each one of the observable completes.
`merge` will let obs run async, `scan` will take a count and send to `map` to workout the percentage

```
obs=[ob1,ob2,ob3]
merge(...obs).pipe(
  scan((acc,curr)=>acc+1,0),
  map(count=>count/obs.length*100)
)
```

Comment: And so to get the results of `[ob1,ob2,ob3]` I can do `zip(...obs)` right after merge?

Comment: Sorry for the trouble I found the exactly what I need as an example on RxJS site. :)
https://www.learnrxjs.io/recipes/progressbar.html / 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-5-progress-bar-wxdxwe?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=50

Comment: but please note that the example provided doesn't not execute asynchronously, it will be slower to use concatAll

Comment: You probably meant not executed in parallel, because they do executed asynchronously...

Comment: the example execute in sequence learnrxjs.io/recipes/progressbar.html

Comment: Yes, but it is asynchronous anyway.

Comment: Call itself is async but Comcatall will queue each one up and won’t run in parellel, if u don’t mind that

Answer (score 0):

One more possibility:

```
function get_result_and_perceptage(obs)
  const counter$ = new Subject();
  obs_modified_list = obs.map(item => item.pipe(finalize(
    () => counter$.next(1)
   ))

   const result$ = forkJoin(obs_modified_list).pipe(finalize(
     () => counter$.complete()
   ));

    const percent$ = counter$.asObservable().pipe(map((val)=>count *100/obs.length));
    return {result$, percent$};
```

Usage:

```
obs=[ob1,ob2,ob3]; // netwofk calls oservables

 const {result$, percent$} = get_result_and_perceptage(obs)
 result$.subscribe((resData)=>handleData(resData))
 percent$.subscribe(
    (percentValue) =>showItSomethere(percentValue),
    null,
    doSomethingWhenIsDone()
  )
```

Comment: Created an article about forkJoinWithProgress implementation:  https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-recipes-forkjoin-with-the-progress-of-completion-for-bulk-network-requests-in-angular-5d585a77cce1

Comment: Hi Alexander, Thanks for the article. It helped me a lot. I was just wondering if there is any way to know if any specific request has got completed in the same example. Can you please suggest ?

Comment: Hi. Same lib "version": "1.0.1" worked that way but has a bit different api, you cam install and check it. Source code is here: https://github.com/kievsash/rxjs-toolbox/blob/develop/src/lib/forkJoinTransparent.ts     I hope it will help

Comment: Thanks for the update Alexander. I got the code. Can you please let me know which version of Rxjs you have used ? I am having trouble only with the scan function in the method. My Rxjs Version is 5.5

Comment: I used rxjs ver 6